# Kafka timing out connecting to node on macos/Mojave

Tags: spring, macos, apache-kafka

Using the quick start here

```
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
```

I followed the steps but when I execute

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

I get:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

I change the list command to

bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

It works fine.

I try to run these samples

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/master/samples
```

Non work and i get:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

This happens on a corporate/company laptop

I do the same steps using on my private macos (Sierra) using

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

It works fine and all spring samples work as well

On the machine not working:

I tried using the IP listed by kafka here

```
[2020-02-28 14:12:31,202] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 (/92.242.132.25:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Like this `--bootstrap-server 92.242.132.25:9092` That didn't help

btw that ip address (92.242.132.25) isn't the same as the one i get from ifconfig which is:

```
192.168.1.35
```

I tried both and didn't help.

However `telnet localhost 9092` does connect.

- Any idea what's happening? Why `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092` isn't working?
- Why the IP addresses (from kafka start-up output and ifconfig) are different?
- Could the corporate mac-os have some restriction (firewall etc) that could cause this? Asked support they said no.

Comment: try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: thanks, 127.0.0.1 didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

If you just need locally running Kafka to develop against, Confluent Platform on Docker is much simpler to get up and running, see https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html